# DataTables row.add() function does not add all rows from the array

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, datatables, row

I'm working on a travel portal and using DataTables JS Plugin To Populate results.

"search.results" is an array of JSON objects each containing search results, However, only first 30 are getting populated and the rest don't.

console does not log any errors and all search objects appear when logged in console from within the "for" loop.

I need all the results to be populated in the table.

Kindly Help, Thanks in advance.

```
**datatable declaration**

 var oTable = $('#search').DataTable({
"bDestroy": true,
"aaSorting": [[4, 'asc']],
"bPaginate": true,
"bInfo": false,
"bFilter": true,
"bScrollCollapse": true,
"fnInitComplete": function() {
    this.fnAdjustColumnSizing(true);
}
});

**results population**

for(var j=0; j<search.results.length; j++){
oTable.row.add([
search.results[j].airline,
search.results[j].from,
search.results[j].to,
search.results[j].duration,
search.results[j].fare,
'<button id="button-'+j+'" class="btn btn-change1 book_btn"  type="button">book</button>',
]).draw();
};
```

Comment: this is the actuall code : http://pastebin.com/1G1u7Wzk

Comment: I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/1568/) which emulates what you're trying to do.  It works ok for me.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML, and `search.results`?

Answer (score 1):

You are using search.results.length in your for loop and search result is limited to 30 in your paginate (due to **"bPaginate": true**)
Try to override default limit in your query or just set bPaginate to false